# Stop 2 Conflicting Scripts Running At The Same Time

Tags: filemaker, schedule

I have two scripts that do the same thing but for different companies, and during the process they both use the same tables.

It's imperative that only one script runs at once, as sometimes the timings vary greatly, and they are scheduled rather close together purposely. My question is, what is the best method to ensure these scripts do not run together? I tried to have a global field, set to 1 at the beginning of the script, and 0 at the end, so when the 2nd script runs, if global field = 1 - exit script -

This did not work, as both these scripts are scheduled server side, and I have read that the GLOBAL variable is local in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, we are talking about FileMaker Server schedules.

Global variable will be reset every time you run a scheduled script. Every script will run on it's own session. You can not use them to ensure the scripts do not clash.

As far as I know, FileMaker Server does not run two schedules at the same time. The second script will be delayed until the first one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

FileMaker Server can run simultaneous schedules if they are script schedules, thus an overlap can occur.
What you need to do is set a field that is not a global, so that the schedules can check against the value of that field.
A single record table would be ideal for this.
Make sure that you commit after setting the field, or you may get record locking issues.

Answer (score 0):

Create an OS-level script that uses the fmsadmin command line to run one script, then run the second.

Set the FM Server schedule to run the OS script (which then runs the PSoS scripts).